# Get value from dropdownlist and create another dropdown list

Tags: html, list, button, drop-down-menu

I have created a dropdownlist and it looks like this

```
 <select id="mySelect">
       <option value="one">Do one</option>
       <option value="two">Do two</option>
      </select>
```

Firstly I would like NOT to have a submit button. The second thing I was searching is that when I select the first choice to appear another dropdown list and when i choose the second to appear a text input for the user to type something. Thank you and sorry for the English!

Comment: well, at least you should show that you were trying to write some code before giving this task. If you wrote the code and it did not work, we would like to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to import any jQuery you can still do it with pure JavaScript.

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/7uoft06b/2/)

Just include the below script in your file as,

```
function myFun(){
    var val = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var input = document.getElementById("myIn");
    var sel = document.getElementById("myOtherSelect");
    var sub = document.getElementById("mySubmit");
    if(val.value == "one"){
        sel.style.display = "block";
        input.style.display = "none";
        sub.style.display = "none";
    }else if(val.value == "two"){
        input.style.display = "block";
        sub.style.display = "block";
        sel.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        input.style.display = "none";
        sub.style.display = "block";
        sel.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Now add the onchange event on your select as,

```
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFun()">
       <option value="emp" selected>Choose something</option> 
       <option value="one">Do one</option>
       <option value="two">Do two</option>
    </select>
    <select id="myOtherSelect">
       <option value="three">Do three</option>
       <option value="four">Do four</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="myIn">
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmit">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...it helped me a lot... i wanted pure javascript and html..the thing is that i want the text input to show up(along with a button) when i click option two on the first select..do you have any idea?

Comment: @elenaa which button are you talking about?

Comment: @elenaa Do you want the textbox and dropdown to be available in single line?

Comment: Generally I want a dropdown list with two options. If someone chooses the first option an another dropdownlist appears. If someone chooses the second option a text input and a button("submit") appears.

Comment: @elenaa Check out my updated answer and updated demo

Comment: @elenaa Glad it helped, you can accept the answer if you think it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do something simple like:

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  $('#input').html('<input name="myname" value="'+this.value +'">');
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf44bc9t/)